# How Execute Azure data bricks notebook from excel

Tags: python, excel, azure, pyspark, databricks

Is there any way to trigger Azure data bricks notebook from excel, if is there please help me how..?

Many thanks

Comment: please check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/connect-databricks-excel-python-r?msclkid=0d79e22fd04c11ec91e6e808762cb0da

Answer (score 1):

Lets address the elephant in the room. Why? I'm not normally one to question the intention but it seems fundamentally a bad idea to execute a databricks notebook via excel. I suspect its a misunderstanding of how databricks works.

That aside.

**Consume Data into Excel**
If you wish to consume data from existing tables in databricks follow this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/connect-databricks-excel-python-r?msclkid=0d79e22fd04c11ec91e6e808762cb0da

**Execute a Notebook via Excel**
This should be possible although I've never tried from Excel.
1st you need to understand the difference between a notebook and a job. As per the docs:

> A job is a way to run non-interactive code in an Azure Databricks cluster.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-engineering/jobs/jobs

So now you understand you are able to submit your notebook as a job. How do you achieve this?

1. You will need to create your notebook and have it within your databricks workspace (consider [using Widgets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/widgets) to parameterise it)
2. You will need to [generate a PAT token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/access-control/tokenslbnM&ntb=1) or assign a [Service Principal the correct permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/users-groups/service-principals) (if using SCIM)
3. You will then use the above details to query the [Jobs API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs) with your notebook path and any parameters via a Macro (VBA in your Excel Document). [Example for a different API here](https://tonicanada.medium.com/api-calls-from-excel-f364bc68e316)